# CMD program "for" loop error

Tags: cmd

```
echo off
set apk[0]=apk
for /r %%a in (.apk) do call array.bat add apk %%a
call array.bat len apk length
echo apk files found = %length%
for /l %%G in (1,1,%length%) do (
call array.bat getitem apk %%G item
echo %item%
)
echo Pick one:
set /p pick=
call array.bat getitem apk %pick% chose
echo.
echo You picked %chose%.
pause
```

In the above code i get length of apk array as 9 but the for loop prints ECHO is off 10 times?!
I am able to access to individual elements of the array o_O and also down the code after the user picks the choice it displays correctly. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a very quick fix, try

```
call echo %%item%%
```

This is generation 7,863 of `delayedexpansion`. There are hundreds of SO entries on this subject. Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

Note therefore the use of `CALL ECHO %%var%%` which displays the changed value of `var`. `CALL ECHO %%errorlevel%%` displays, but sadly then RESETS errorlevel.

Note also that your item-displayed using your original code is the **last** item set in a prior run. You do not have a `setlocal` command in your batch, so the environment changes are established permanently, not backed out at the end of each batch. The consequence is that you are running with a contaminated environment.

Comment: setLocal Enabled solved the issue which i didnt actutally understand >.< but i will google it